# TortoiseGit - git does not pull

Tags: git, tortoisegit

[image]

I am using tortoiseGit. 
I am facing some issue in Git-Pull. When I select Git-Pull, I get 1st window given in the screen shot & if I select okay then I get second window. This second window stays as it is & does not go forward.
This used to work before but not sure why it is stuck now?

Comment: Without more information, I feel this is impossible to answer.  Have you tried a pull on the command line?

Comment: I have tried it from eclipse & it's working fine .. I know this info is not sufficient but not sure what settings I need to check as I am new to Git

Comment: I'm not too familiar with tortoise, do you know if it keeps logs?  I'd check there first, assuming it does.

Comment: Maybe you're just having temporary network issues since "this used to work before"? Maybe you should consider learning how to use git from the command line. TortoiseGit is a terrible git GUI anyways, too much TortoiseSVN influence.

Comment: Ok. I think there is definitely some issue with tortoiseGit because I am able to pull using command line ... thx

Comment: Using SSH? See http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1880

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue seen mainly with origin using an ssh url.

See for instance [issue 1880](https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1880):

> It looks like our gerrit server is not respecting the SSH protocol properly.
>   There was a change in putty/plink 0.63 where they do some ssh winadj commands.
>   They are expecting a reply response from ssh but it never gets sent.  Therefore the plink simply waits until it gets these reply responses.
>
> It's possible that the latest gerrit server has a fix although I didn't see any note of that on their release notes.  Putty has a workaround though:
>
> 1. Run putty for windows 0.63.
> 2. Click on "`Default Settings`" in the `Saved Sessions`. Click `Load`,
> 3. Go to `Connection -> SSH -> Bugs`
> 4. Set "`Chokes on PuTTY's SSH-2 'winadj' requests`" to `On` (instead of `Auto`)
> 5. Go Back to Session in the treeview (top of the list)
> 6. Click on "`Default Settings`" in the `Saved Sessions` box.  Click Save.
>
> Now that bug setting will be saved for all running instances of plink/putty and including tortoisegitPlink.